# Parênteses ou travessão: qual escolher?

Tags: gramática

As orações intercaladas podem ser separadas da oração principal através do uso de parênteses. Porém, na maioria das vezes, acabo optando pelo uso do travessão.

Vejam o seguinte exemplo:

> Esses povos costumavam usar a planta inteira (as raízes, o caule e
> também as folhas) no preparo dos mais diferentes alimentos.

> Esses povos costumavam usar a planta inteira – as raízes, o caule e
> também as folhas – no preparo dos mais diferentes alimentos.

De alguma forma, para mim, a segunda construção parece mais correta, embora ambas apresentem o mesmo sentido.

Do ponto de vista gramatical, existe alguma regra ou orientação específica que sugere o uso de um (parênteses) ou outro (travessão)?

Comment: Yes, it does! Thank you very much.